# What issue are .NET Standard and .NET Core intended to solve?

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I've read some things about .NET Standard and .NET Core, and generally they seem to say something like "This is the new way to do things, and here are the advantages and disadvantages."

What I haven't seen is a good, clear explanation of what was wrong with the status quo, such as .NET Standard and .NET Core were even necessarily.  To really judge what I should use these for, it would be helpful to know why they exist at all.

Can someone give a clear (and not necessarily concise!) explanation of (a) what *problem* .NET Standard and .NET Core are intended to solve, and (b) how they solve it?

Answer (score 9):

.NET Standard is a set of library contracts. Each version includes all the contracts of the previous version - so everything in netstandard1.4 is in netstandard1.5 for example.

.NET Core is an implementation of .NET Standard (and some extra functionality) which runs on Windows, Linux and OSX.

Biggest problems they solve:

- Not having a Microsoft-provided/supported toolchain and runtime on Linux/MacOSX. Saying that you could only run .NET-based server code on Windows or Mono was simply untenable.
- The Portable Class Library mess with hundreds of different profiles giving partially-overlapping API surfaces to target.

PCLs in particular were very hard to work with for class library authors such as myself. The mess came about because there were multiple efforts to bring a .NET runtime to different devices without enough coordination to provide a coherent API surface to target.

Now multiple vendors can target particular versions of .NET Standard, and anything targeted to that version or higher should work. For example, my Noda Time library targets netstandard1.3. Suppose a new mobile phone vendor comes out with a completely new implementation of .NET, with a completely new kind of application - but says they support netstandard2.0. That's fine - a user of that new platform will still be able to install the Noda Time NuGet package and (implementation bugs aside, of course) they'll be able to use it. I don't need to know that the platform even exists.